Minimum Cell Changes to Ensure Unique Numbers in Each Row and Column of an $ n \times n $ Table
We have an $ n \times n $ table, and in each cell of the table, there is a number from $1$ to $ 2n $. We want to change the numbers in some of the cells and replace them with other numbers from $1$ to $ 2n $ such that in the end, all the numbers in each row and each column are distinct. What is the minimum number of cells we need to change?
I have tried using dynamic programming and assumed the subproblems are $i\times i$ minors of the grid. However, I couldn't make significant progress with this approach. I also attempted to reduce the problem to graph problems, such as matchings, but again, I didn't succeed in finding a solution.
Any hints or help would be immensely valuable to me.

Do you care more about theoretical complexity or practical running time on real-world instances?  If the latter, what are typical values for $n$ and for the number of cells that must be changed?

@D.W. Constraints on $n$ are $1\leq n \leq 300$.

Hint 1
If we have a cell $a_{i,j}$ which is duplicate to some other cell $a_{i, j_1}$ in its row, and some other cell $a_{i_1, j}$ in its column; we can always remove this duplicacy by only changing $a_{i,j}$. This is because the maximum number of unique numbers in the row $\cup$ column are $2(n-1)$ and we can select from $2n$ numbers, leaving us with a choice of atleast $2$ numbers.
Hint 2
Following the above hint, the crux of the problem remains on how to optimize number of changes on $(i, j)$'s where $a_{i,j}$ is duplicate both in the row and column. If the frequency of number $k$ in row $i$ is $f^r_{i, k}$ and in column $j$ it is $f^c_{j, k}$, then the answer is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \max(f^r_{i, k}-1, 0) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \max(f^c_{j, k}-1, 0) - g(k) \right) 
$$
where $g(k)$ is some number produced by optimising on the common cells. Note we can't just add all the number of common cells as $g(k)$ (take the counter example of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$)
Hint 3
To compute $g(k)$, make a weighted directed graph $G=(V, E)$ with
$$\begin{split}
V&=\{S\} \\ 
&\cup \{{r_1}, {r_2}, \dots {r_n} \} \\
&\cup \{c_1, c_2, \dots c_n\} \\
&\cup \{T\}
\end{split}$$
and
$$\begin{split}
E&=\{(S, r_i, \max(f^r_{i, k}-1, 0)) : \forall 1\le i \le n\} \\
&\cup \{(r_i, c_j, 1): \forall 1\le i, j \le n \text{ if } a_{i,j} = k\} \\
&\cup \{(c_j, T, \max(f^c_{j, k}-1, 0)) : \forall 1\le j \le n\}
\end{split}$$
Then the max flow of this graph is $g(k)$
Example
Consider $n=5$ and the table to be $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 9 & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

For $k\in \{4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8, 10\}$, we don't see a single cell $a_{i,j} =k$. So $$\begin{split} h(k) &=  \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \max(f^r_{i, k}-1, 0) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \max(f^c_{j, k}-1, 0) - g(k) \\ &=0 \end{split}$$

For $k=9$, we see only a single cell $a_{4,4} = 9$. So $h(9) = 0$ too.

$k=3$ is also trivial with $h(3) = 1$

$k=2$'s graph $G$ has a max flow of $6$ (as seen in the image below)  So $$\begin{split} h(2) &=  \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \max(f^r_{i, k}-1, 0) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \max(f^c_{j, k}-1, 0) - g(k) \\ &= 6 + 6 - 6 \\ &=6 \end{split}$$

$k=1$'s graph $G$ has a max flow of also $6$ (as seen in the image below)  So $$\begin{split} h(1) &=  \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \max(f^r_{i, k}-1, 0) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \max(f^c_{j, k}-1, 0) - g(k) \\ &= 7 + 6 - 6 \\ &=7 \end{split}$$


So total number of changes required is $7 + 6 + 1 = 14$, as shown in the below table.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red} 4 & 2 & \color{red} 3 & \color{red} 5 & 1 \\
2 & \color{red} 3 & \color{red} 4 & 1 & \color{red} 5 \\
\color{red} 3 & \color{red} 4 & 1 & 2 & \color{red} 6 \\
\color{red} 5 & 1 & 2 & 9 & 3 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 5 & \color{red} 6 & \color{red} 3 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Algorithm runtime analysis
For each number $k$, let $f_k$ denote the total number of cells $a_{i, j} =k$ in the table.
Time complexity of

Finding $f^r_{i, k}$ and $f^c_{j, k}$ for all $i, j, k$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$
Calculating max flow of graph $G$ for $k$ using ford fulkerson is $\mathcal{O}(EF) = \mathcal{O}((n+f_k) f_k)$ in worst case, but closer to $\mathcal{O}(n + f_k)$ in practice.

Then the time complexity is $$\begin{split}
T &= \mathcal{O}(n^2) + \sum_{k=1}^{k=2n}( 2 \cdot \mathcal{O}(n) + \mathcal{O}(n + f_k)) \\
&= \mathcal{O}(n^2) + \mathcal{O} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{k=2n} f_k \right) \\
&= \mathcal{O}(n^2)
\end{split}$$
